# What is the class of keywords like def, alias, and begin in Ruby, if any?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, keyword, superclass

As far as I understand, everything in Ruby is an object, and every object has a superclass, except `BasicObject`, which is at the top of the inheritance tree.

What is the superclass of keywords like `def`, `begin`, and `alias`?

Comment: As far as I am aware, every class has a super class. To clarify, no keyword has a super class. But every class has the super class Object.

Comment: Those keywords are merely ruby-language identifiers, they don't belong to and are not classes. When the notion of "everything is an object" is said, it is meant in the context of how data is handed in ruby, in other words, that there are no primitive values like you find in Java or other languages.

Comment: Keyword parsing happens in... well, the parser. They're language syntax artifacts, not written in Ruby (for MRI, anyway).

Comment: @Emz just for clarifications sake the highest level of class is actually `BasicObject` as of 1.9. `Object.superclass #=> BasicObject` and `BasicObject.superclass #=> nil`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're keywords, not objects. If anything, they would be methods in [`Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html), and have class `Method` as a result, but they're just keywords, and as such have neither class nor superclass. They're a special case and treated specially by the interpreter; they're parsed to produce the abstract syntax tree that the interpreter actually executes, and probably long gone by the time anything involving objects and classes is done. After all, how would `end` work as a method?

Note that not everything that looks like a keyword *is* one. Take, for example, `loop`:

```
loop do
  puts 'Hello, world!'
end
```

While it may look like a keyword, it's actually the method [`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop).

By far the easiest way to tell if something is a method or a keyword is to run this long, complicated code on it:

```
method(name_to_test)
```

where `name_to_test` is either a Symbol literal or an instance of Symbol. It uses the always-available method [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-method), which either returns the `Method` with that name or throws a `NameError`. If it operates silently -- i.e. doesn't raise any errors -- then you've got a method; if it raises an error, it's not a method. Note that it could also be a variable, not a keyword or method, but it should be easy enough to tell by looking at the previous code in the file, and a quick search through the docs.

If you want to see the current list of keywords (or don't feel like booting up IRB/your favorite IDE), check [this file](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L886) in the RMI source. It's a little hard to understand, but basically, if you see `keyword_[thing you're looking for]` in that list (possibly with a leading `_` removed), it's a keyword. To make this answer as self-contained as possible, here's the (current) list of keywords, based on that:

> `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `__ENCODING__`, `BEGIN`, `END`, `alias`, `and`, `begin`, `break`, `case`, `class`, `def`, `defined`, `do`, `else`, `elsif`, `end`, `ensure`, `false`, `for`, `in`, `module`, `next`, `nil`, `not`, `or`, `redo`, `rescue`, `retry`, `return`, `self`, `super`, `then`, `true`, `undef`, `when`, `yield`, `if`, `unless`, `while`, `until`

(Many thanks to [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky) for pointing the list out! Never would have found it on my own.)